# Why does the state variable `zone` return null after reading from a CSV file with d3 in a React component?

Tags: reactjs, csv, d3.js, react-hooks

I'm working on a React component where I need to read data from a CSV file using d3 and store the result in a state variable. I've separated the initialization in a `useEffect` hook, but when I try to use the `zone` state variable after reading the CSV file, it returns `null`.

Here's the relevant code:

```js
const ItalyMapRegion = ({ w, h, onChangeRegion }) => {
  const [zone, setZone] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("once");
    d3.csv(data).then(function (data) {
      setZone(data);
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(zone); // This returns null, why?
    // ...
  }, [zone]);

  // ...
};
```

What am I doing wrong here, and why is the `zone` state variable null after reading the CSV file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the operation happened in the first `useEffect` is asynchronous. Try to add the `zone` variable as a dependency to the second `useEffect` and check if it is there:

```
const ItalyMapRegion = ({ w, h, onChangeRegion }) => {

  const [zone, setZone] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("once");
    d3.csv(data).then(function (data) {
      setZone(data);
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (zone) {
      console.log(zone);
    }
  }, [zone]);
```

Comment: ok, but if i do this the second useEffect its run twice. There's a waty to run also the second useEffect only once?

Comment: The second `useEffect` must run twice: on initial rendering when the `zone` variable is `null` and the second time when it changes after you set `data` to it. It can't run once.

Perhaps you should restructure your app a bit, for example move data fetching outside the component, it actually depends on what you need to do. We have not much information on that.

Comment: Yea, i think i need to do a little bit of refactoring, thanks!